# How to create data in database only once

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I need to make a method,which will add data to database,and then,spinner should display it. As i tested,displaying works fine,but i don't know,how i can tell database,that i want to create some data only once. For example,i have table named chestExercises with three columns firstColumn,secondColumn,thirdColumn that have values :

```
firstColumn = "exerciseOne"
secondColumn = "exerciseTwo"
thirdColumn = "exerciseThree"
```

Now,i want from program to create those data only once. As i wrote before,i've make some "tests" and database keeps creating those data all the time,i don't want to have duplicates. So.. How i can "tell" database,that i want to make it only once?

Database

```
 public databaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_2 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_3 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_4 + " TEXT)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, "1");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, "2");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, "3");
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}

public List<String> getAllLabels() {
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
            labels.add(cursor.getString(3));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    if (spinner == null){
        db.insertData();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    loadData();
}

public void loadData(){
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labels);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String label = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(),"Selected: "+label,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

Comment: i think what you want no duplicate data..right?

Comment: your question is contradictory...one time creating mean can be like you just want one row in database

Comment: please be more specific what exactly one time mean

Comment: It's not contradictory. I cleary definied what it should like, but ok, i will repeat that. I want to create some method, who will generate data in specific rows. For example, let's imagine database contains body building exercises. Database should look like:

Table name = chestExercises 
first row: firstExercise = some exercise
second row: secondExercise = some exercise

I want to make it something like final,it won't by edited,and it has to be created only one time untill user delete app (so it should be create only one single time,this data will be shown in spinner)

Comment: Well you can use shread preferences.... You can check if applications is first time opened... If yes then insert else load data

Comment: In else you can also make it like if no data then insert else load data

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1 - Have a suitable constraint

One option would be to define the table so that the 3 columns combined form a **UNIQUE** constraint and thus will result in a conflict if the combined columns exist.

e.g.

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_2 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_3 + " TEXT," + COLUMN_4 + " TEXT, UNIQUE (" + COLUMN_2 + "," + COLUMN_3 + "," + COLUMN_4 + " ))");
```

In which case the same combination of values would not be inserted (as the `insert` method effectively uses INSERT OR IGNORE, so if a conflict arises the INSERT is ignored).

#### Option 2 - Check the table's row count

An alternative method could be to check to see if the table already has any data by checking the row count.

You could have a method in the DatabaseHelper class such as :-

```
public boolean isTableEmpty(String tablename) {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(this.getWritableDatabase(),tablename) < 1;
}
```

- Of course this could be modified to test for other scenarios

#### Option 3 - Query the table to see if the row exists before inserting e.g.

```
public boolean insertDataCheckingForDuplicate(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowcount = 0;

    String whereclause = COLUMN_2 + "=? AND " + COLUMN_3 + "=? AND " + COLUMN_4 + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{value1,value2,value3};
    Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    rowcount = csr.getCount();
    csr.close();
    if (rowcount > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_2, value1);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_3, value2);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_4, value3);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

#### Option 4 - Use a pre-loaded database.

With this method you supply a pre-loaded database (i.e. the base data exists). The database is placed in the assets folder a copied from the assets folder to the relevant location when the database is first opened. The process looks to see if the database exists, if it does then the database is opened, if it does not then the database is copied.

You can use SQLiteOpenAssethelper to simplify this process, see [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). There are also numerous examples of how to do this yourself on StackOverflow.